# Avoid static initializer for lists of image and video formats?

Tags: java, image, reflection, static, video

I wrote the following code to read constants from annotations:

```
public class ContentUtils {
    static {
        String[] videoFormats = null;
        String[] imageFormats = null;
        try {
            Field multipartFileField = MultipartFileWrapper.class.getField("multipartFile");
            Extensions annotation = multipartFileField.getAnnotation(Extensions.class);
            imageFormats = annotation.imageFormats();
            videoFormats = annotation.videoFormats();
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            if (imageFormats == null) {
                imageFormats = new String[]{};
            }
            if (videoFormats == null) {
                videoFormats = new String[]{};
            }
        }
        ACCEPTED_IMAGE_FORMATS = imageFormats;
        ACCEPTED_VIDEO_FORMATS = videoFormats;
    }

    public static final String[] ACCEPTED_IMAGE_FORMATS;
    public static final String[] ACCEPTED_VIDEO_FORMATS;
}
```

Is there a way to rewrite it better?

Or something else improve at this code?

Comment: which call in there might throw `NoSuchFieldException` ?

Comment: MultipartFileWrapper.class.getField("multipartFile");

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! To make life easier for reviewers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. See also [this meta question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/code-should-include-a-description-of-what-the-code-does)

Answer (score 7):

According to your comment,
if it's only the `MultipartFileWrapper.class.getField("multipartFile")` statement that might throw a `NoSuchFieldException`,
then when that happens, the lines that set `imageFormats` and `videoFormats` will not be reached, so these values will remain `null`, and the `if` conditions in the `catch` block are pointless.

Furthermore, it's good to minimize the scope of `try-catch` blocks.
Consider this reworked version:

```
static {
    Field multipartFileField = null;
    try {
        multipartFileField = MultipartFileWrapper.class.getField("multipartFile");
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        // maybe log that something bad happened?
    }
    if (multipartFileField != null) {
        Extensions annotation = multipartFileField.getAnnotation(Extensions.class);
        ACCEPTED_IMAGE_FORMATS = annotation.imageFormats();
        ACCEPTED_VIDEO_FORMATS = annotation.videoFormats();
    } else {
        ACCEPTED_IMAGE_FORMATS = new String[]{};
        ACCEPTED_VIDEO_FORMATS = new String[]{};
    }
}
```

Here, I don't need to ask what might throw the `NoSuchFieldException`,
it's obvious, which is good.

As for avoiding the static initializer...
if you want to have static fields with non-trivial constants,
then there's just no other way,
you have no choice but to initialize them in a static initialization block like this.
Other option would be to give up the static fields,
make them non-static and initialize in the constructor.
But this probably won't make much sense,
since the field values come from static data (`MultipartFileWrapper.class`).

Comment: multipartFileField.getAnnotation(Extensions.class); can returns null. It will reason of NPE

Comment: The original code didn't handle such case, so I didn't suspect either. If necessary, it can be added easily.

Answer (score 5):

The worst part is actually

```
public static final String[] ACCEPTED_IMAGE_FORMATS;
public static final String[] ACCEPTED_VIDEO_FORMATS;
```

publishing both arrays for everyone to modify them at will. Ideally, use Guava's `ImmutableList`. Otherwise, use `Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList(....))`.

---

If you don't mind letting the initialization do some trivial work twice, you can write

```
private static ImmutableList<String> initAcceptedFormats(boolean forImage) {
    Field multipartFileField;
    try {
        multipartFileField = MultipartFileWrapper.class.getField("multipartFile");
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        return ImmutableList.<String>of();
    }
    Extensions annotation = multipartFileField.getAnnotation(Extensions.class);
    return ImmutableList.copyOf(forImage ? annotation.imageFormats() : annotation.videoFormats());
}

public static final ImmutableList<String> ACCEPTED_IMAGE_FORMATS = initAcceptedFormats(true);
public static final ImmutableList<String> ACCEPTED_VIDEO_FORMATS = initAcceptedFormats(false);
```

---

I'd go for it. The use of the `boolean forImage` is not nice, but for a private two-shots method it's better than introducing an `enum` or whatever. I'd also avoid the daniel' Java 8 idea as (while it's nice), it adds a new interface and two hidden anonymous classes.

---

In my solution, `annotation` gets computed twice. This "problem" should be surely ignored, but in case of a repeated *expensive* computation, a `private static final` variable can be introduced.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a private static Method to initialize the fields.

```
public class ContentUtils {
  public static final String[] ACCEPTED_IMAGE_FORMATS = getAcceptedImageFormats();
  public static final String[] ACCEPTED_VIDEO_FORMATS = getAcceptedVideoFormats();

  private static String[] getAcceptedImageFormats() {
        try {
            Field multipartFileField = MultipartFileWrapper.class.getField("multipartFile");
            Extensions annotation = multipartFileField.getAnnotation(Extensions.class);
            return annotation.imageFormats();
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            return new String[0];
        }
    }
    private static String[] getAcceptedVideoFormats() {
      // ...
    }
}
```

Is it better? I don't know. The Oracle Documentation says you can use this method later to reinitialize the variables.

The duplication that results, with this almost identical Methods can be eliminated with lambda Expressions, if Java 8 is available.

```
public class ContentUtils {
  public static final String[] ACCEPTED_IMAGE_FORMATS = getAcceptedFormats(a -> a.imageFormats());
  public static final String[] ACCEPTED_VIDEO_FORMATS = getAcceptedFormats(a -> a.videoFormats());

  private static String[] getAcceptedFormats(FormatAcceptor acc) {
        try {
            Field multipartFileField = MultipartFileWrapper.class.getField("multipartFile");
            Extensions annotation = multipartFileField.getAnnotation(Extensions.class);
            return acc.acceptedFormats(annotation);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            return new String[0];
        }
    }

  interface FormatAcceptor {
    String[] acceptedFormats(Extensions annotation);
  }
}
```